# Why is the ruby install so slow

Tags: ruby

The recommended way to install ruby is through rvm and rbenv.

Why are these methods so slow? I have seen packages 10x times larger installing
in much quicker time.

Answer (score 1):

Because they compile a fresh copy of ruby for each versioned installation. That ought to have been obvious from both the documentation and the output of rvm.

Comment: Maybe `rvm` is more informative, but the [non-obvious] output of `rbenv` is the following hang for ten minutes: "Installing ruby-X.Y.Z ..."